# Battery indicator missing for amd 64 raring

Tags: indicator, battery

I dont find the battery indicator for my amd 64 Toshiba Satellite. It points to this resource which is not found:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Any fix available? My notebook shuts down without any notice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the S.M.A.R.T drivers installed for your battery? (If your computer supports it) your system is most likely turning off due to low battery. go to Toshiba's website and browse through their drivers until you find your notebooks battery driver. Install it. **Make Sure That It Is Your Model Of Notebook's Battery!** If your system was originally running Windows, When it boots up, spam F2 or F8 until you see a menu "BIOS" check there and run a start up test, and then run a full system Diagnosis. Hope this helped you

Comment: I had it running windows earlier...Then installed 13.04 completely removing windows...I do F2 and i find no BIOS menu to run a start up test..Will try updating the drivers now